# Django rendered content is different in console.log from page source

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have the following code in my django view project:

```
if request.method == "POST": 
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        datas = Order()
        datas.user = current_user
        datas.save()

        current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%H%S%m%M%d')
        order_number = current_datetime + str(datas.id)
        datas.order_number = order_number 
        datas.save()

    order = Order.objects.get(user=current_user, is_ordered=False, order_number=datas.order_number)

    context['order'] = order
    context['user'] = request.user

    return render(request, 'orders/order.html', context)
```

Inside order.html, I have:

```
<script>
    console.log('order number 0: ', {{ order.order_number }})
</script>
```

When I view the page source and browser console, the values of **{{ order.order_number }}** are different. Browser console.log shows wrong values for **str(datas.id)** part whereas the rest of the part of **{{ order.order_number }}** is same in both console.log and page source.

Comment: View page source may just be requesting the page from the server again, you should probably look at the DOM or the network tab instead.

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, I found the error. In templates, console.log({{ order.order_number }}) and console.log('{{ order.order_number }}') both give different results. console.log('{{ order.order_number }}') displayed the correct order number. But why the results are different, I have no answer.